# Show that there exists a rainbow cycle in the complete graph on n vertices, where no color appears more than $(n-1)/2$ times?

Tags: graph-theory

Show that there exists a rainbow cycle (all edges of distinct color) in the complete graph on n vertices, where no color appears more than $(n-1)/2$ times? Also show that there exists a rainbow triangle.

My intuition tells me I can apply the pigeonhole principle in this problem, but can't seem to get my foot off the ground with the proof.

Comment: If we find a rainbow triangle would that count as a rainbow cycle for the first question, or did you want a rainbow cycle of a specified length, like for instance $n$? Because as it stands, asking first for a cycle and then for a triangle seems a bit redundant.

Comment: That's a good point. I was confused by that addition as well. For now, I am focusing on showing the existence of a rainbow cycle and asking for clarification on the triangle. My best guess would be he is first asking for the existence of a rainbow cycle in general, and then for a rainbow cycle of length 3.

Comment: Unless I am missing something finding a rainbow cycle where no color appears more than (n-1)/2 times is equivalent to finding a cycle of length (n-1)/2 because in rainbow cycle all colors have to be unique lol. This is trivial in a complete graph.

Comment: D'oh. Thank you for that @user2879934 your comment made me realize the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've figured out the solution:

A complete graph $K_n$ has $n(n-1)/2$ edges. Since each color appears at most $(n-1)/2$ times, there must be at least $n$ different colors.

Since there are at least more colors than vertices, it is trivial to find a rainbow cycle in the complete graph $K_n$.

There will always be an outgoing edge of a different color from any of the edges you've traveled on already to make a cycle since all vertices are connected to each other (all vertices have degree $n-1$ and there are at least $n$ colors).

It follows that there exists a rainbow triangle in $K_n$ for $n \ge 3$.

Since the graph is complete and all vertices are connected by an edge, and there are at least $n$ colors and $n \ge 3$, there will always be at least 3 different colors to choose an edge from when forming a triangle.

Let me know if my logic is sound.